# Is there any other bash code I can use other than grep?

Tags: bash

The bash script provided below is to tell user that the file has already appended previously therefore, you are not able to do it again. To chose another file

```
grep -Fq "code:123456" $f
if [[ $? == 0 ]];
then
  echo "File1 has already been appended to $f"
else
  echo "File appended to $f"
fi
```

Comment: grep is a quite nice solution here ; you did well of course you can use many solutions awk/vi/vim/sed *as script mode for vi or vim* & even pure bash in fact grep is historically itself a `g/re/p`  vi command

Comment: "What are all the possible approaches to doing X?" is generally too broad to be on-topic here; it's basically an infinite set.

Comment: Why do you ask, do you have any problems with grep?

Comment: @Dominique im new to writing bash so im trying to get more understanding on how to use it

Comment: Is the string being checked the value to be appended? or the name of a faile to append? Your code does neither. Please clarify what it is you are trying to do so we can help you with a good solution, and help you to understand it in a way that will help others reading it later.

Comment: Try a simple awk - `awk -vkey="$code" '$0 ~ key { hit=1; exit 1; }
END{ if ( hit ) { printf "code %s already in %s, aborting.\n", key, FILENAME; } else { printf "%s\n", key >> FILENAME; printf "%s appended to %s\n", key, FILENAME; } }' $file`

Answer (score 1):

One pure Bash way:

```
found=""
while read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
        *code:123456*)
            found=1
            break
    esac
done < "$f"

if [ -n "$found" ] ; then
    echo 'Found!'
else
    echo 'Not found!'
fi
```

I still prefer your code, just putting `grep` in the `if` condiition:

```
if grep -Fq "code:123456" -- "$f"; then
  echo "File1 has already been appended to $f"
else
  echo "File appended to $f"
fi
```

Comment: are you able to elaborate more on the -m? what do you mean by multiple hits? as in something got to do with duplicate?

Comment: @Yatee `-m`  limits the amount of things `grep` for, so it exits only after only 1 in this case. upon reflection, `-q` does this anyway, so it's redundant and I removed it.

Comment: Double quote $f in the condition to prevent globbing and word splitting?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Reading a file line-by-line in `bash` is horribly slow. There's no reason to reimplement `grep` in `bash` like this.

Comment: @chepner You should probably ping OP, or comment under the question.

Comment: another question. how can i call the file (.txt only) in the root folder? /root/*.txt?

Comment: f=" /root/school/*.txt"
if grep -Fq "code:123456" -- "$f"; then
  echo "File1 has already been appended to $f"
else
  echo "File appended to $f"
fi

is this correct?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Thanks for the explaination

Comment: @kabanus Thanks for the explaination

Comment: for the nickpickers... I know `[[` is pure bash built-in, but isn't `[` just a synonym for `test`? Or does bash wrap some syntactic sugar around that and handle it "in-house" as well?

Comment: @Paul the former, you are correct.